# How to send a video to the server?

Tags: python, sockets

The code works, but only when the file is sent, it comes with a duration of a couple of seconds, maybe this is due to open-cv!
My code:
Server:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("localhost", 4344))

server.listen()

user, adres = server.accept()

print('Connect')

file = open('po.avi', mode='wb')
data = user.recv(102400)

while data:
    file.write(data)
    data = user.recv(102400)
```

Client:

```
import socket
import cv2

flag = True
count = 0

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect(('localhost', 4344))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 50) 
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', codec, 25.0, (1280, 720))

while count != 300:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
    print('s')
    frame = out.write(img)

    count += 1

file = open("output.avi", mode='rb')
data = file.read(102400)

client.send(data)
data = file.read(102400)

file.close()
client.close()
out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When the code ends, the file is sent, but only the duration of the video is less than a second

Comment: isn't that because the client only sends less than a second? 102400 bytes?

Comment: You have a loop for receiving arbitrary amount of data, but there's no such loop in the sending code.

Comment: Send the whole file: `client.sendall(file.read())`